# Connect to remote server through another server using a one line command

Tags: linux, ssh, bash

I have two servers: server1 and server2
I can connect to server2 only from server1 by a specific user.
Currently, I connect like this:

1. My computer `ssh user@server1`
2. On server1: `su - user2`
3. After this on server1 `ssh user3@server2`

How can I do use one command line from my computer?

Comment: Why don't you connect directly as `user2` to server1?

Comment: I can't control ssh keys o this servers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use jump hosts:

```
 ssh -J host1 host2
```

Then in your `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host host1
   hostname X.X.X.X
   user user1
Host host2
   hostname X.X.X.X
   user user2
```

Comment: This was cool. Never tried it before

Comment: before connecting to host2 I need do su - user2 and next use ssh user3@host2
user1 -me
user2 - user on host who can login like user3 on host2

Comment: You should use `ProxyJump` in the configuration file and shorten the command line to `ssh host2`.

Answer (score 0):

as a start, try:

```
ssh user@server1 "su - user2 -c 'ssh user3@server2'"
```